# How to access events of the Masonry object in angular-masonry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, masonry

I am using successfully angular-masonry by Passy in a project.

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Which is the best away to access the events function of the Masonry object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution>

```
    $scope.$on('masonry.created', function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $log.debug('Masonry created');

    var masonObj = element;

    $log.debug('This is masonry', masonObj);


});
```